# Configuration of SSI in IIS 7

Tags: iis, server-side-includes, ssi, shtml

I've installed ServerSideIncludes module on my computer and it works great with one exception.

```
<!--#include virtual="meta.inc" -->
```

The line above is causing the problem. I know I must change `virtual` with `file` but I have a huge website and it means I must change at least 1000 line of code like this and I am looking for a way to run `virtual` properly in IIS 7.

I've been looking for this solution but all I've been able to find the solution I've mentioned above.

Do you know how to solve this problem without changing the `virtual` to `file`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have parent paths enabled over your site?  Navigate to the "ASP" section of your site in IIS and select "Enable Parent Paths" in the "Behavior" section and see if that helps.

The Parent Paths option permits you to use ".." in calls to functions such as MapPath by allowing paths that are relative to the current directory using the ..\notation. Setting this property to True may constitute a security risk because an include path can access critical or confidential files outside the root directory of the application.

Comment: I can't see such thing in my IIS and I am not using classic Asp btw.

Comment: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/566/classic-asp-parent-paths-are-disabled-by-default/

reference about 1/2 way down on the page

Comment: Even it looks appropriate for this question, it wouldn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer but instead is more a confirmation of your problem. But see one possible way that `virtual` might work for you at the end of my answer.

From the MSDN blog post [IIS: Notes on Server-Side Includes (SSI) Syntax (KB 203064 Revisited)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2010/12/28/iis-notes-on-server-side-includes-ssi-syntax-kb-203064-revisited.aspx) *(dated 2010-12-28; applies to IIS versions 4.0 through 7.5)*:

---

**More Information on File and Virtual Syntax**

SSI directives that use file paths can reference files by using a **file** or **virtual** path.

- The **file** element is used with files that are relative to the folder of the current document. The following example includes a file in the current folder:

```html
<!--#include file="myfile.txt"-->
```

- The **virtual** element represents paths that are relative to the base folder of the Web server. The following example includes a file in the /scripts virtual folder:

```html
<!--#include virtual="/scripts/myfile.txt"-->
```

---

**Conclusion:** The `file` attribute is used to designate a file location that is relative to the current document. So, if that is what is needed in your situation, you'll indeed need to change the `virtual` attribute to the `file` attribute.

There is one possible exception, though. The article [Server Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes#Most_common_directives) on Wikipedia shows the following example:

```html
<!--#include virtual="menu.cgi" -->
```

This suggests to me that a `virtual` file path does *not* necessarily need to begin with a `/`. In the absence of a leading `/`, the location of a `virtual` file is relative to the base folder of the web server.

So, it appears to me that the `file` and `virtual` attributes might behave identically ***if*** the files being referenced happen to be located in the base folder (or subfolders of the base folder) of the web server.

Answer (score -1):

SSI is not ASP -- they're different technologies.

I have found that each time Microsoft releases a new version of any of their products that sometimes certain features that worked in previous versions work differently or not at all in the newer versions, and it looks like this problem may be one of those.

So, you might want to consider switching to Apache HTTPd (if you can) and then you won't need to make all those changes to your files -- I've found that Apache has been consistent in their support for SSI (and other technologies/modules, configuration directives, etc.) in all versions of HTTPd that support it.  This consistency is one of the reasons I really like it.