# PHP shared header without using sever-side scripting?

Tags: php, html

Simple problem I have so far always solved via PHP:

You have a site with header, menu, footer and content field.

Header, menu and footer are usually the same for each page.

- How do you, without PHP or any other server-side language, have the header, menu and footer data exist only in one file?

So that for example you don't have ten pages (like home.html, products.html, about.html, ..) all having a copy of the static header and menu in their html files. Now if you want to change the header you have to change ten files.

I hope I made my question clear enough, if not please leave a comment :)

Comment: Seems like the answers have the "how" covered pretty well.  I've gotta ask though **why would you want to do this?**

Comment: looks like you try to solve typical task with inadequate methods. beware of that!

Comment: @RomanArmy Seriously, you hard code your navigation into every page of your site?  I guess that's ok (in practice, not principle), if you have a two page site, but I think it's pretty standard practice (and good practice) to have shared navigation, headers, add areas, info blobs (welcome back $UserName, it's been $Days since we last say you...), etc. across a site, or sections of one.  Otherwise, 98% of your maintenance is spent propagating simple updates through your 10,000 pages to change a link in the navigation.

Comment: +1 for: Why would anyone see the need to down-vote this question?

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Overflow cyggi.

Comment: @Eli: I guess my comment was a bit vague, I understand why you'd want to re-use code.  I just don't understand the "no server side language" requirement.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this without server side scripting? I think even most free hosters provide PHP these days. So why not use it?

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Apache, you can use [server-side includes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html).  These basically provide include statements within HTML documents.

Install and enable `mod_include`. Configure

```
Options +Includes
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

Use `.shtml` as your main page file extension. Then in your pages, you can do things like

```
<!--#include virtual="/header.html" -->
```

---

Nginx also supports [server-side includes](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html) with it's SSI module:

```
location / {
    ssi on;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!--# include file="header.html" -->
```

Comment: *"[...], without PHP or any other server-side language[...]?"*

Comment: @cyggi, this is without any server-side language.  Apache itself parses the file to include other files.

Comment: @cyggi This doen't not have anything to do with PHP. It is built into Apache. It doesn't require any 'real' server-side language, so I say it would fit your use perfectly.

Comment: A "language" is only something Apache doesn't do itself? And what is a "real language" in that regard? (turing complete?)

Comment: You can also do this with IIS, or at least you could years ago, before I switched away from Redmond...

Comment: @Eli: You can still do it with IIS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827786/configuration-of-ssi-in-iis-7

Comment: I have to wonder: how is using mod_includes really different from using mod_php?

I suppose maybe mod_includes ships with most apache binaries by default while mod_php doesn't necessarily?

Comment: -1: While the answer gets around the letter of the question (and even that is arguable... it has variables and control structures, for example), it blatantly ignores the intent.

Comment: @Bemrose: How so?  It involves no server-side programming, as requested. The "intent" is to use no PHP or other server-side scripting, which this does.

Answer (score 5):

Frames can do this. Can't say much about the quality of the result though.

Comment: Don't even try. There are good reasons why most sites don't use frames anymore.

Comment: The other route is to use iframes, or something with JavaScript to insert elements into the DOM, but those are just as nasty.

Answer (score 4):

Could also do it entirely with client side scripting.  Just execute some async requests to get static resources and inject them into the page.  This is really just a JS version of frames and not the best way to approach the problem, but it'd work.

Comment: You *could* go skinny dipping in the Arctic Circle, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea ;)

Comment: @mattbasta: Pretty much.  To be fair the question asked how, and most people have included a disclaimer that it's a bad idea in their answers =).

Comment: @mattbasta: I also feel obligated to point out that just because it's not a good idea usually doesn't keep people from doing it http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1BrcL-ENfI.

Comment: I've heard of a lot of sites that only have a script include in the actual html file. I do not recommend this but hey it works I guess

Answer (score 1):

if your host support shtml files, they have limited scriptability.

```
<!--#include file="included.html" -->
```

otherwise, for plain html, you're out of luck i'm afraid, unless you have some fancy javascript/ajax that does it.

Comment: Nowadays it's easier to find a host with PHP support than SSI one %)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's *exactly* what you mean, but you can do this with [SSI (server-side includes)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/ssi.html) instead of server-side scripting. SSI isn't scripting, it's just a way of including other files without writing any real code.

As for doing this without the server's help altogether, that's a different story. You're better off using the server to do this kind of thing. It feels dirty, you end up with weird files all over, and it's a pain to manage, but templates and includes do a fairly decent job of doing what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript templating, like that provided by [Underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template) or [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/templates/). More likely: **refuse to work for clients who will not pony up for appropriate web hosting,** and are basing that decision solely on cost rather than what is appropriate for the site.

Answer (score 0):

One option that you have is to include the header in references JS file where you have document.write() wrapped around the header.  Of course, I do not use this method for my own code since I usually do PHP or VB.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way I can think of that doesn't involve a server language (but *does* involve server-side processing) is [server side includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes).

Answer (score 0):

If you had to, and without frames, ajax requests to get the data would be best. Though, as mentioned, would kill seo

Answer (score 0):

If you can use javascript and jQuery, you can dynamically load header and footer using $.load. Not the most clean solution though.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I like best is to, since you know PHP, produce a PHP script that, given a folder of templates, produces a folder of final HTML files for you to upload. Sounds like a decently easy task, actually.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions of using PHP `include` or Apache server-side includes are true, these would solve the problem.

But I suggest another option specific to PHP, if you know that *every* page has the same header and footer:

- `auto_prepend_file`
- `auto_append_file`

See docs at http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php